# Stored Procedure resultset into sub query in another SP

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I want to use stored procedure result into inside of another stored procedure , like sub query. Is it possible..?

Below Sample Code : Password generation Logic created in one sp:

```
Create Procedure GetDynamicPassword
@Password out
As

Begin

    -- Password generate Logic createhere
        -- More than 100 line to generate password logic


End
```

I want to use the above result into another SP.

Unable to use temp table, because i need this result for so many records in single time.

I want to use above sp inside the below sp.

```
Create Procedure GetDynamicUsers


As

Begin


    Select a.col1, b.col2 , c.col3...
    ( I want to uses password here from above SP )
        ( like exec GetDynamicPassword) As Password 
        from Table1 As a
    inner join Table2 As b on a.Code = b.Code
        inner join Table3 As c on a.Code = c.Code 
    inner join Table4 As d on a.Code = d.Code


End
```

Comment: you can use function in query but not proc .
exec GetDynamicPassword inside GetDynamicUsers and store it int temp table.why can't you do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite your stored procedure `GetDynamicPassword` as a [Scalar valued User-Defined Function](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191007.aspx).

Then you can use the function directly in your select statement.

Answer (score 1):

The best practice to do that would be to create a function and then call it in your SP

```
Create function GetDynamicPassword
returns varchar(100)
As

Begin

-- Password generate Logic createhere
    -- More than 100 line to generate password logic


End
```

and then use it in your SP below

```
Create Procedure GetDynamicUsers

As

Begin

Select a.col1, b.col2 , c.col3...,
dbo.GetDynamicPassword() As Password 
    from Table1 As a
inner join Table2 As b on a.Code = b.Code
    inner join Table3 As c on a.Code = c.Code 
inner join Table4 As d on a.Code = d.Code


End
```